# Is there a way to import HTML into JavaHelp?

Tags: import, automation, netbeans-platform, javahelp

I'm trying to automate JavaHelp generation from a book (HTML) already on the web to bundle as a NetBeans module. Is there a way to automate the conversion into JavaHelp format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you writing your book? If you're using DocBook then you can generate JavaHelp directly from it.

Comment: There's an epub version of it that I can convert into DOcBook and then to JavaHelp.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you can use [JHelpDev](http://jhelpdev.sourceforge.net/) to create Java Help sets from existing HTML.  It looks pretty simple to use but I can't attest to it's quality.